# Edit file from Sourcetree in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, atlassian-sourcetree

In Sourcetree you can right click a file (from current commit / branch) to edit, it then opens a window where a script target can be entered. What to fill in there so it opens the PhpStorm editor?

I work with a Mac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah.. with the finder click on a file, show info, open with, change all.

Then open in Sourcetree will use that application.